# Preg Replace code for json string

Tags: json, preg-replace

I want to replace all sequential commas `,,` with `{"v":""}`
for example `,,,,,` would also be replaced.

I've tried

```
preg_replace('/,+/',',{"v":""},', $string);
```

Though I probably got something wrong.  Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
preg_replace('/,{2,}/', ', {"v":""}', $string);
```

However, a simple regular expression isn't the best tool for this job because it will break as soon as there is a string containing multiple commas.

Comment: thank you that worked, i also noticed that `/,,+/` works as well. I however don't understand why you said it is not the best too though.

Comment: What I mean is that if you apply the substitution on valid JSON data that looks like this: `{"summary": "two commas,, in a string"}` you'll end up with invalid JSON. Where you want to perform the substitution is context-sensitive and for that regexp is not the best tool.